# Drag N Drop using jdwidgets - dataAdapter loadComplete table column names display OK; but dataAdapter.dataBind() data display is clumped together

Tags: javascript, data-binding, drag-and-drop

Problem with Drag N Drop using jdwidgets component. My jdwidgets dataAdapter loadComplete event completes OK for showing the table column names OK; but when the dataAdapter.dataBind() event fires, then the result data display is clumped together, rather than formatted under the table columns. Before I tested this code inside my new web html page; I had a successful jdwidgets drag N drop using this same code as copied from the widget demo page; I removed all demo dependences and it worked before I move this same exact code into my new html page. The only difference I had was that the original test code used the  tag to insert the grid data views; my new web html page has  tag to insert the grid data views. This later configuration appears not to work, even though the original code did in fact work using the  tag to insert the drid data view.

after .dataBind() data display is clumped together

[image]

```
<body data-spy="scroll">    
    <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="assets/img/athena_logo_name.png" alt="Athena Logo">
                </a>
                <h1>Customer Portal</h1>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "jsonp",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'countryName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'population', type: 'float' },
                    { name: 'continentCode', type: 'string' }
                ],
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 50,
                    username: "jqwidgets"
                }
            };

            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
                loadComplete: function () {
                    // get data records.
                    var records = dataAdapter.records;
                    // get the length of the records array.
                    var length = records.length;
                    // loop through the records and display them in a table.
                    var html = "<table border='1'><tr>"
                    html += "<th>Grower Name</th>"
                    html += "<th>Field Name</th>"
                    html += "<th>Field #</th>"
                    html += "<th>Solids %</th>"
                    html += "</tr>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        var record = records[i];
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += "<td>" + record['countryName'] + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + record["name"] + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + record["population"] + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + record["continentCode"] + "</td>";
                        html += "</tr>";
                    }
                    html += "</table>";
                    $("#table").html(html);
                },
                loadError: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                },
                beforeLoadComplete: function (records) {
                }
            });
            dataAdapter.dataBind();

            $("#grid1").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                source: dataAdapter,
                pageable: true,
                autoheight: true,
                sortable: true,
                rendered: function(type)
                {
                    // select all grid cells.
                    var gridCells = $('#grid1').find('.jqx-grid-cell');

                    // initialize the jqxDragDrop plug-in. Set its drop target to the second Grid.
                    gridCells.jqxDragDrop({
                        appendTo: '#dragdrop',  dragZIndex: 99999,
                        dropAction: 'none',
                        initFeedback: function (feedback) {
                            feedback.height(25);
                        },
                        dropTarget: $('#grid2'), revert: true
                    });
                    gridCells.off('dragStart');
                    gridCells.off('dragEnd');
                    gridCells.off('dropTargetEnter');
                    gridCells.off('dropTargetLeave');

                    // disable revert when the dragged cell is over the second Grid.
                    gridCells.on('dropTargetEnter', function () {
                        gridCells.jqxDragDrop({ revert: false });
                    });
                    // enable revert when the dragged cell is outside the second Grid.
                    gridCells.on('dropTargetLeave', function () {
                        gridCells.jqxDragDrop({ revert: true });
                    });
                    // initialize the dragged object.
                    gridCells.on('dragStart', function (event) {
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        var position = $.jqx.position(event.args);
                        var cell = $("#grid1").jqxGrid('getcellatposition', position.left, position.top);
                        $(this).jqxDragDrop('data', {
                            value: value
                        });
                    });
                    // set the new cell value when the dragged cell is dropped over the second Grid.      
                    gridCells.on('dragEnd', function (event) {
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        var position = $.jqx.position(event.args);
                        var cell = $("#grid2").jqxGrid('getcellatposition', position.left, position.top);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            $("#grid2").jqxGrid('setcellvalue', cell.row, cell.column, value);
                        }
                    });
                },                
                selectionmode: 'singlecell',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Grower Name', dataField: 'countryName', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Field Name', dataField: 'name', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Field #', dataField: 'population', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Solids', dataField: 'continentCode' }
                ]
            });

            $("#grid2").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                selectionmode: 'singlecell',
                autoheight: true,
                source: { totalrecords: 10, unboundmode: true, datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'countryName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'population', type: 'float' },
                    { name: 'continentCode', type: 'string' }
                ]
                },
                columns: [
                   { text: 'Master Name', dataField: 'countryName', width: 200 },
                   { text: 'Alias', dataField: 'name', width: 200 },
                   { text: 'Alias', dataField: 'population', width: 200 },
                   { text: 'Alias', dataField: 'continentCode' }
                ]
            });       
        });
    </script>

        <!-- OVERVIEW -->
        <section id="overview">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section-heading">
                  <h2 class="heading">ORIGINAL DATA REVIEW / EDIT</h2>
                </div>
                <p class="text-center lead">Review your data.</p>    
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- END OVERVIEW -->

        <section id="detail">
            <div class='dragdrop'>
                <div id='jqxWidget'>
                    <div id="grid1"></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 20px; float: left;" id="grid2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: check console if required file not loaded or paste above your block `<script>` and `css`

Comment: Thanks, I did check the console for all <script> and css files; all are loading fine OK. that is not the problem.